# Olhar para multiplos campos em um required_if no Validator do Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5

Estou desenvolvendo uma validação do laravel onde, a obrigatoriedade de um campo vai depender do valor de dois outros campo.

```
{
    "fieldA": true,
    "fieldB": false,
    "fieldC": "Ola, mundo"
}
```

Eu preciso que o campo `fieldC` seja obrigatório apenas se o campo `fieldA` OU `fieldB` for `true`

O `required_if` não aceita mais de um campo como parâmetro e o `required_with` não da pra especificar o valor que outros campos precisa ter.

Comment: Estou utilizando Lumen!

Comment: Veja se esta resposta te ajuda https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36274940/required-if-laravel-with-multiple-value

Comment: Não, inclusive, antes de criar a pergunta eu já tinha caído nessa resposta. Nesse exemplo, ele está olhando dois valores possíveis de um mesmo campo, no meu caso, são campos separados. O required_if aceita multipolos valores, mas não múltiplos fields. Mas obrigado pela resposta :)